# Surface.fill() not working in my pygame program even though it is (0, 0, 255) and the .fill() function is inside the main loop

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win_x = 1000
win_y = 400
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_x, win_y))

pygame.display.set_caption("i think its caled binary sort")

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

array = [3, 9, 7, 5, 8, 3, 1]
picarray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

four = pygame.image.load("four.png")

run = True
while run:
    win.fill(BLUE)

    win.blit(four, (0, 0))

    for i in range(0, len(array) -1):
        for a in range(0, len(array)-1 -i):
            if array[a] > array[a+1]:
                print(array)
                array[a], array[a+1] = array[a+1], array[a]
    print(array)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

i have stated that the colour BLUE is (0, 0, 255) and in my main loop it says win.fill(BLUE) but for some reason i am getting a black screen when i run the program.

Comment: After drawing to the screen you need to `update` or `flip` the screen using `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()`. This should be done at the end of the loop as should drawing to the screen.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. Seems dumb that i left it out :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call `pygame.display.flip()` within your `run` loop, near the bottom:

```
while run:
    win.fill(BLUE)

    win.blit(four, (0, 0))

    // sort
    ...
    print(array)

    // look for quit
    ...

    pygame.display.flip()
```

It would also improve your code quality to move your sorting and `//look for quit` code into separate functions.

Your sorting algorithm is called "bubble sort", because the highest value 'bubbles' to the top, followed by the next highest, and so forth.  You can make it a bit more efficient by also pushing the lowest value to the bottom, highest, then lowest, then highest remaining, then lowest remaining, and so forth... though that code is considerably more complex.  What you have here is probably the simplest-to-code sorting algorithm.

And given how many elements you're sorting, efficiency really isn't a big deal.

Oh, and `called` is spelled with two 'l's.  ;)

EDIT:

One other thing... pygame requires that your `render` a font, and blit that rendered text at a particular position in order to draw it.  Unless you've written some code elsewhere to handle all that, you're going to `print` your array to standard output, not your pygame window.

There's a text rendering tutorial here:
https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part5

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My program is sorted now but to answer your question, yes later on in going to blit the images of my numbers